# Extraction data from MySQL table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i'm trying to extract data from mysql. I have some query looking like this `SELECT q1, COUNT(*) FROM results GROUP BY q1` and as result I'm expecting something like this:

```
q1  COUNT(*)
0   7
1   1
2   4
3   1
```

It works in phpMyAdmin workflow, but if I try to repeat this query from my pagename.php file I'm failed.

```
$q1_ans = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT q1, COUNT(*) FROM results GROUP BY q1");
$q1_arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q1_ans);
foreach($q1_arr as $key => $value) {
        echo "<br>$key is at $value";
      }
```

And as result I have

q1 is at 0
COUNT(*)  is at 7

How can I get array looking like this??

```
0 is at 7
1 is at 1
2 is at 4
3 is at 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_assoc()` fetches ONE row from the database. You have to repeat it until there is no more data:

```
$q1_ans = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT q1, COUNT(*) FROM results GROUP BY q1");
while ($q1_arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q1_ans)) {
    foreach($q1_arr as $key => $value) {
        echo "<br>$key is at $value";
    }
}
```

This fixes the issue that you only get one result. To fix your output, see @sagi's answer.

Comment: thank you for your help, getting only first row was my big trouble

Answer (score 3):

You can do it directly in the query :

```
"SELECT CONCAT(q1,' is at ',COUNT(*)) as YourName
 FROM results GROUP BY q1"
```

This will return them as one field.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution